# How to use recursive function that converts csv file to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

i'm trying to figure out how to create a recursive function (PHP) that merges csv file into a multi dimensional array.

i got a csv file that looks like this

```
id,parent_id,date
1,0,2017
2,1,2017-01
3,1,2017-02
4,1,2017-03
5,1,2017-04
6,1,2017-05
7,1,2017-06
8,1,2017-07
9,1,2017-08
10,1,2017-09
11,1,2017-10
12,1,2017-11
13,1,2017-12
14,0,2018
15,14,2018-01
16,14,2018-02
17,14,2018-03
18,14,2018-04
19,14,2018-05
20,14,2018-06
21,14,2018-07
22,14,2018-08
23,14,2018-09
24,14,2018-10
25,14,2018-11
26,14,2018-12
27,0,2019
28,27,2019-01
29,27,2019-02
30,27,2019-03
31,27,2019-04
32,27,2019-05
33,27,2019-06
34,27,2019-07
35,27,2019-08
36,27,2019-09
37,27,2019-10
38,27,2019-11
39,27,2019-12
```

and the output should be like this -

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [2] => 2017-01
                    [3] => 2017-02
                    [4] => 2017-03
                    [5] => 2017-04
                    [6] => 2017-05
                    [7] => 2017-06
                    [8] => 2017-07
                    [9] => 2017-08
                    [10] => 2017-09
                    [11] => 2017-10
                    [12] => 2017-11
                    [13] => 2017-12
                )

        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [15] => 2018-01
                    [16] => 2018-02
                    [17] => 2018-03
                    [18] => 2018-04
                    [19] => 2018-05
                    [20] => 2018-06
                    [21] => 2018-07
                    [22] => 2018-08
                    [23] => 2018-09
                    [24] => 2018-10
                    [25] => 2018-11
                    [26] => 2018-12
                )

        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [28] => 2019-01
                    [29] => 2019-02
                    [30] => 2019-03
                    [31] => 2019-04
                    [32] => 2019-05
                    [33] => 2019-06
                    [34] => 2019-07
                    [35] => 2019-08
                    [36] => 2019-09
                    [37] => 2019-10
                    [38] => 2019-11
                    [39] => 2019-12
                )

        )

)
```

i'm reading the csv file into an array, with this output -

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => id[1] => parent_id[2] => date
    ) [1] => Array(
        [0] => 1[1] => 0[2] => 2017
    ) [2] => Array(
        [0] => 2[1] => 1[2] => 2017 - 01
    ) [3] => Array(
        [0] => 3[1] => 1[2] => 2017 - 02
    ) [4] => Array(
        [0] => 4[1] => 1[2] => 2017 - 03
    ) [5] => Array(
        [0] => 5[1] => 1[2] => 2017 - 04
    ) [6] => Array(
        [0] => 6[1] => 1[2] => 2017 - 05
    ) [7] => Array(
        [0] => 7[1] => 1[2] => 2017 - 06
    ) [8] => Array(
        [0] => 8[1] => 1[2] => 2017 - 07
    ) [9] => Array(
        [0] => 9[1] => 1[2] => 2017 - 08
    ) [10] => Array(
        [0] => 10[1] => 1[2] => 2017 - 09
    ) [11] => Array(
        [0] => 11[1] => 1[2] => 2017 - 10
    ) [12] => Array(
        [0] => 12[1] => 1[2] => 2017 - 11
    ) [13] => Array(
        [0] => 13[1] => 1[2] => 2017 - 12
    ) [14] => Array(
        [0] => 14[1] => 0[2] => 2018
    ) [15] => Array(
        [0] => 15[1] => 14[2] => 2018 - 01
    ) [16] => Array(
        [0] => 16[1] => 14[2] => 2018 - 02
    ) [17] => Array(
        [0] => 17[1] => 14[2] => 2018 - 03
    ) [18] => Array(
        [0] => 18[1] => 14[2] => 2018 - 04
    ) [19] => Array(
        [0] => 19[1] => 14[2] => 2018 - 05
    ) [20] => Array(
        [0] => 20[1] => 14[2] => 2018 - 06
    ) [21] => Array(
        [0] => 21[1] => 14[2] => 2018 - 07
    ) [22] => Array(
        [0] => 22[1] => 14[2] => 2018 - 08
    ) [23] => Array(
        [0] => 23[1] => 14[2] => 2018 - 09
    ) [24] => Array(
        [0] => 24[1] => 14[2] => 2018 - 10
    ) [25] => Array(
        [0] => 25[1] => 14[2] => 2018 - 11
    ) [26] => Array(
        [0] => 26[1] => 14[2] => 2018 - 12
    ) [27] => Array(
        [0] => 27[1] => 0[2] => 2019
    ) [28] => Array(
        [0] => 28[1] => 27[2] => 2019 - 01
    ) [29] => Array(
        [0] => 29[1] => 27[2] => 2019 - 02
    ) [30] => Array(
        [0] => 30[1] => 27[2] => 2019 - 03
    ) [31] => Array(
        [0] => 31[1] => 27[2] => 2019 - 04
    ) [32] => Array(
        [0] => 32[1] => 27[2] => 2019 - 05
    ) [33] => Array(
        [0] => 33[1] => 27[2] => 2019 - 06
    ) [34] => Array(
        [0] => 34[1] => 27[2] => 2019 - 07
    ) [35] => Array(
        [0] => 35[1] => 27[2] => 2019 - 08
    ) [36] => Array(
        [0] => 36[1] => 27[2] => 2019 - 09
    ) [37] => Array(
        [0] => 37[1] => 27[2] => 2019 - 10
    ) [38] => Array(
        [0] => 38[1] => 27[2] => 2019 - 11
    ) [39] => Array(
        [0] => 39[1] => 27[2] => 2019 - 12
    )
)
```

and i'm trying to apply this array on this function that should get me the output that i wanted

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}

$tree = buildTree($MyArray);
```

but i just cant figure out how to apply the recursive function over here, and how to use the 'parent id' and 'id' elements in the foreach scope...
i'm really lost at this point.

Comment: I don't see any reason for recursive function.

Comment: i see that, but this is what the lecturer asked for.. @u_mulder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `for` loop can be converted into recursive function. You can create the following recursion function:

```
function setElement($res, $arr) {
    if (count($arr) == 0)
        return $res;
    $e = explode(",",array_shift($arr));
    if (isset($res[$e[1]]))  
        $res[$e[1]]["dates"][$e[0]] = $e[2]; // if exist add it
    else $res[$e[0]] = array("date" => $e[2], "dates" => []); // not existed yet - so init it
    return setElement($res, $arr);
}
```

Then use it with (example):

```
$arr = ["1,0,2017", "2,1,2017-01", "3,1,2017-02", "14,0,2018", "15,14,2018-01", "16,14,2018-02"];
$res = setElement([], $arr);
```

Now `$res` will contain your desire output.

**Edit:**

If your data comes from csv file you need to load them first. You may use [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) as the follow function:

```
function getCSVarray($path) {
    if (($handle = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $keys = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $res[] = array_combine($keys, $data);
        }
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Now use as:

```
$res = setElement([], getCSVarray("array.csv"));
```

**Notice to modify `setElement` as now the indexes changed!**

As:

```
function setElement($res, $arr) {
    if (count($arr) == 0)
        return $res;
    $e = array_shift($arr);
    if (isset($res[$e["parent_id"]]))  
        $res[$e["parent_id"]]["dates"][$e["id"]] = $e["date"]; // if exist add it
    else $res[$e["id]] = array("date" => $e["date"], "dates" => []); // not existed yet - so init it
    return setElement($res, $arr);
}
```

**Edit 2**:

Using your array (`$MyArray`) you can use:

```
function setElement($res, $arr) {
    if (count($arr) == 0)
       return $res;
    $e = array_shift($arr);
    if (isset($res[$e[1]]))  
        $res[$e[1]]["dates"][$e[0]] = $e[2]; // if exist add it
    else $res[$e[0]] = array("date" => $e[2], "dates" => []); // not existed yet - so init it
    return setElement($res, $arr);
} 

//using it as:
array_shift($MyArray); // extract first element as it is the keys
$res = setElement([], $MyArray);
```

Comment: i am trying to use you're example (which looks great) 
and i'm using the array like this -
`$arr = 'array.csv'` (the csv file that contains the list, they are in the same folder of course) , and then using this $arr var like you used it, but it is not working for me... any idea why?

Comment: i'm getting this error - Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in D:\Computers\htdocs\Project\array.php

this line -   $e = explode(",",array_shift($arr));

Comment: @Àtishking as I said - you need modification - updated my answer accordingly

Comment: first of all - i want to thank you for your patience, this is so not taken for granted.
second of all, im using 

$res = setElement([],  $MyArray);  (MyArray is the array i loaded from the csv file)

and than your function - and it is - still not working.
i am getting error of " Undefined index id / parent id / date and so..."

Comment: Can you please share the output of the ` $MyArray` after extract the csv file? (can put post only the first 3 elements)

Comment: i edited the main question again - and posted the output of the array over there

Comment: The array you posted does not use my function of `getCSVarray` - as the first line are not set as the array keys. I also saw you change your function to `buildTree` so it change your question a bit...

Comment: at this part $res = setElement([], getCSVarray("array.csv"));
i didnt understand why i need to use the getCSVarray function, if i already imported the csv file into an array ("$MyArray")

Comment: @Àtishking add another edit in order to fit your array

Comment: @Àtishking is it working for you now? if so please mark it as accepted so other may know to use it (the green "v" mark at the left of the post) - Glad to help!

Comment: if you got extra time, a little bit of explanation about what you exactly did there will be really helpful.

Comment: Sure - first I used `shift` to pop the first element of the array as it is the headers (=keys). Then, in the recursive function I took the first element of the array and insert him to the right position (add to element or init new sub-array). Afterward, called the function again with 1 element less. Stop condition for the function is empty input array

Comment: Bravo! You helped me so much.